# solo me remplaza el primer resultado que encuentra en python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x

tengo este código

```
>     from datetime import datetime, timedelta
> 
> FILENAME = 'Token' now = datetime.now() result = now +
> timedelta(hours=8)
> 
> print(f'device_profile=DASH_TV_WIDEVINE&start_time={now:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ}&end_time={result:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ}')
> with open(FILENAME, 'w') as token_file:
>                 token_file.write(f'device_profile=DASH_TV_WIDEVINE&start_time={now:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ}&end_time={result:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ}')
>                 
>                             with open("plantilla.txt", "rt") as plantilla:
>     with open("X-Tcdn-Token", "rt") as token:
>         with open("nuevotoken.txt", "wt") as nuevotoken:
>             for linea in plantilla:
>                 if 'headers=' in linea:
>                     linea = linea.replace('headers=', f'headers={token.readline().rstrip()}').rstrip()
>                 nuevotoken.write(linea)
```

el original es un archivo que tiene varias URLs y quiero agregar el resultado del archivo token al final de esas URLs que terminan en headers= pero solo me escribe la primera

si alguien me puede ayudar